# Rotating x-axis labels in R for RcmdrMisc::plotMeans

Tags: r, plot

How do I flip the X-Axis labels 90 degrees in a `RcmdrMisc::plotMeans`. (not the axis title). As it's not showing all my insect family names along the axis. `las=` doesn't seem to work

`with(Data, plotMeans(Count, Insect, Site, connect=TRUE))`

[image: Click for Plot of Means Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding arguments las = 2 and cex.axis = .8 to your graph.
Las changes the orientation and cex.axis changes the font size so values can fit side-by-side.

Comment: Doesn't change a thing. Has no effect on font size either. Maybe 'plotMeans' isn't changed in the same way as other plots... hmmm